# Why the total sum of squares has $n-1$ degrees of freedom

Tags: linear-regression, sums-of-squares

Let $\textbf{y} = [Y_1, \dotsc, Y_n]^T$ and $\textbf{y}^* = [Y_1 - \overline{Y}, \dotsc, Y_n - \overline{Y}]^T$. Apparently, by subtracting the mean from each of its coordinates, there is linear restriction on $\textbf{y}^*$, ensuring that $\sum(Y_i - \overline{Y}) = 0$. The sum is zero because
$$\sum(Y_i - \overline{Y}) = \sum Y_i - n\overline{Y} = n\overline{Y} - n\overline{Y} = 0.$$
$\textbf{Question:}$
Among the $n$ values of $Y_i - \overline{Y}$, why only $n-1$ are linearly independent?

If I understand this, then I know why the total sum of squares TSS $= ||\textbf{y}^*||^2 = \sum(Y_i - \overline{Y})^2$ has $n-1$ degrees of freedom. This is because degrees of freedom associated with a sum of squares represent the dimension of the subspace to which the corresponding vector is confined.

Comment: $\sum  (1)(Y_i - \overline{Y}) =  0$ tells you immediately that $Y_i-\overline Y$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: @geetha290krm So because $\sum(Y_i -\overline{Y}) = 0$, there exists $k = 1, \dotsc, n$ such that $Y_k - \overline{Y}$ can be written as a linear combination of the other $n - 1$ entries. Also, $\sum_{j = 1, j \neq k}^{n-1}a_j(Y_j - \overline{Y}) = 0$ if and only if $a_j = 0$ for all $j$. Therefore, $n-1$ entries are linearly independent. Is this correct?

Comment: No at most  n-1 entries are linearly independent some of the  yk could be $yk=\bar{y}$ then it is less.